# How do you create a randomly generated list of items while ensuring there are no duplicates?

Tags: python-3.x, list, random

I am trying to make a function that randomly selects items from a list and makes a new list with a random order of items every time it runs. I believe I have the bulk of it done, however, I am missing a way to make sure that when my function runs, it always generates just one of each item in the list without duplicates (excluding the intentional duplicates I made in my list, ie: I want a list of 16 items with 2 c1, c2, c3, etc but not something like 3 c1, 1 c2, 5 c3).

```
def random_assignment():
list_of_pairs = [c1, c1, c2, c2, c3, c3, c4, c4, c5, c5, c6, c6, c7, c7, c8, c8]
random_list = list(random.choice(list_of_pairs))
keep_generating = True
while keep_generating:
    return random_list
if len(random_list) == 16:
    keep_generating = False
```

Comment: The end two lines are unrechable statements.

Comment: Bad formatting, unclear "data" `c1` etc are not known - Code throws NameError - Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

list_of_pairs = [i for i in range(8)]*2
lista = []
for _ in list_of_pairs[:]:
    lista.append(list_of_pairs.pop(randint(0,len(list_of_pairs)-1)))
```

thers ofcause also the less "correct" way - this is genrally bad practice

```
[list_of_pairs.pop(randint(0,len(list_of_pairs)-1)) for _ in list_of_pairs[:]]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the shuffle function from the random module like this to get a unique set of random integers:

```
import random

my_list = list(xrange(1,100)) # list of integers from 1 to 99
                          # adjust this boundaries to fit your needs
random.shuffle(my_list)
print my_list # <- List of unique random numbers
```

Note here that the shuffle method doesn't return any list as one may expect, it only shuffle the list passed by reference.

Comment: This does not answer Salizmo's question! It was tagged Python 3 yet your answer is Python 2 and you use lists which have no relation (name wise or value wise) to Salizmo's question...

Comment: the question is tagged python 3